# Force www with SEF doesn´t work in Joomla 3

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, sef

When I force redirection from `no-www` to `www` (using htaccess) works fine only with the domain.

`domain.com` (redirect to) → `www.domain.com` **(works fine)**

`domain.com/category/article/` (redirect to) → `www.domain.com/index.php` (**doesn't work**)

First redirects correctly to `www.domain.com/category/article/` ( I can view in the browser) and then quickly change to `www.domain.com/index.php`.

- I used a lot of options in htaccess for redirect domain to www. but nothing works.
- I disable redirection plugin in Joomla.
- If I disable SEF in admin Joomla. Works. With non SEF url works fine.
- In the same server in another website with Joomla 2.5 works fine.

Any idea Please?

Comment: Sharing your htaccess code for the redirect (or list of actions taken if you are using a GUI) would help in tracking your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the www redirect in the wrong place in the htaccess file. Here is my boilerplate htaccess I use as a starting point for all Joomla sites on Apache. I've added it to pastebin as the editor here messes with formatting.

http://pastebin.com/yW9r8FQL

Comment: Thanks cybersholt. True! Redirection had placed on the wrong side. I SOLVED  and I want to thank you for the .htaccess file you provided.

Comment: Hello juanma, no problem at all. Like I said I use this on most of my projects so it's a good one. It's heavily inspired by html5boilerplates htaccess here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess